# Error using lapply to perform regression: variable lengths differ (found for 'x')

Tags: r, regression, lapply

I'm trying to use `lapply` to perform the same multiple logistic regression equation on 68 different variables stored in the vector `fsdata_dict1`. When I try to run the below code, I get the following error: `Error in model.frame.default(formula = binge_dr ~ x + Age_in_Yrs + Race +  :  variable lengths differ (found for 'x')` . No NAs are present in the data, and running str() on the data show all variables have the same number of observations. All variables to my knowledge are defined in the dataset, so I don't believe naming conflicts are the issue.

Code:

```
glm_func <- function(x){
 return(glm(binge_dr ~ x + Age_in_Yrs +  Race + SSAGA_Income + SSAGA_Educ, family = binomial, data = fdata_fs, na.action = na.pass))
}

lapply(fsdata_dict1, glm_func)
```

Comment: formulas are looking for colnames to evaluate from your data, in you case `x` is data itself from a different object altogether. Is `fsdata_dict1` just a copy of columns found in `fdata_fs`??

Comment: @Daniel O I see! Is there another way to perform the regression for every variable stored in the vector? ```fsdata_dict1``` contains a subset of the columns found in ```fdata_fs```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `glm` does not actually change the `x` in the formula to the variable passed as `x` to your function. Assuming `fsdata_dict1` contains the names of the variables you wish to include (as character strings), you can do something like:

```
glm_func <- function(x){
f <- as.formula(paste("binge_dr ~", x, "+ Age_in_Yrs + Race + SSAGA_Income + SSAGA_Educ"))
 return(glm(f, family = binomial, data = fdata_fs, na.action = na.pass))
}

lapply(fsdata_dict1, glm_func)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm now getting an error that says ```Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:31: unexpected symbol
1: binge_dr ~ FS_L_Bankssts_Area Age_in_Yrs
                                  ^  ```, with the ^ below Age_in_Yrs. Does this indicate age is not correctly defined?

Comment: Thank you so so much!